# "Cannot declare class X because the name is already in use" after change in length in Symfony, Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Been scratching my head over this for hours.
I've inherited a large PHP project and it's now my responsibility.
I also admit that I am not very experienced with Symfony.

Looked all over StackOverFlow for help, but still cannot resolve the following issue.
I made a change in **\src\Entity\SOMETHING\BLAH.PHP**

Now when I run **php bin/console make:migration** I get the following error:

> ```
> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
> Compile Error: Cannot declare class App\Entity\SOMETHING\BLAH, because the name is already in use
> ```

All I changed was the string length of a column.

> @ORM\Column(type="string", **length=100**, nullable=true)

- I've tried moving the migration file that defined the table orignally out of the src folder
- I've tried clearing the vendor and node_modules folders, and running
  npm and composer install.
- I've tried cache:clear command

I've searched the code, and the class is only defined once. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: the question is, does the error disappear if you change the length back to its original value? in any case, take a very good look at the error message because you omitted the location of the error. Be certain you do not have some additional version of that file/class somewhere in your source tree. The error can also happen when the class name doesn't match the file name correctly (also directory must match namespace to some extent). if this doesn't help, I hope this is in version control ... check if the diff actually only contains your change and check if the original works.

Comment: Hi @Jakumi , No, the error does not disappear if I change things back. The location of the error is in BLAH.PHP at the top where it says "class BLAH". The class name does match the file name, and the directory does match the namespace too. The diff only contains my change. This is the first database change in a long time to the database according to version control. I cannot speak with the original dev now, but I did ask him before he left, and he didn't say there were any database issues. I suspect there is a stuck cache somewhere or something about Sympony / Doctrine that I've overlooked.

Comment: well you can delete the var/cache sub-directory as well as the vendor dir and run composer install again. there **should** be nothing in those directories that can't be recreated.

Comment: Hi Jakumi, I appreciate the help. I did that, but unfortunately, I still get the error.

Comment: OK, I think I solved the issue. Must be a linux strangeness thing. Did an ls of the directory of the folder \src\Entity\SOMETHING . Everything looked fine. I then moved out the problem file to a temp location with mv \src\Entity\SOMETHING\BLAH.PHP . When I did an ls, I noticed another file with a different case in the directory... Blah.php ! Removed this and moved the file back. No more error. Any explanation?

Comment: in unix/linux Blah.php and BLAH.php are actually different file names, on windows systems by default they aren't (apparently, in win 10 this can be changed). For PHP, though, class names are case insensitive, meaning Blah and BLAH are the same. My assumption would be, that both BLAH and Blah defined their respective classes and also were both read by PHP (the files still both existed but may not have been listed correctly) and thus the class was already defined, hence, the error message. It may also be an editor/git problem that it at some point created an additional file...

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that there were two files in the same directory with the same name, however with a different case *(**BLAH.php** and **Blah.php**)*. For reasons unknown, the "duplicate" files did not show in any source code editor, nor in any **ls** commands to the directory, nor in any text searches with **grep**.

After moving one of the conflicting files, it was noticed when doing an **ls** that the other file with a different case was there. It was not visible prior to moving the file. After removing the other file and moving the original back, then the code compiled.

In summary: a possible file-system glitch was preventing files with the same name but a different case from being visible.